# Ler CSV e guardar em array com variável

Tags: php

Eu tenho um codigo onde eu leio o arquivo EXCEL .CSV e exibo na tela os dados, mas eu preciso guardar esses valores em uma array.

Meu codigo:

```
<?php
$file = fopen(numeros.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
{
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  print_r($line);
}
fclose($file);
?>

$arrayItem= array('8532300022', '8501022934', '8501022969', '8501022926', '8501022985');
```

Teria que ficar algo como:

```
$arrayItem= array('$line');
```

Valew

Comment: Boa tarde, vendo as perguntas que fez, acho que o problema é que você não esta entendendo bem como funciona a linguagem PHP e me parece que você esta querendo aplicar algumas lógicas da "sua cabeça" que não fazem muito sentido, digo isto devido ao autor da resposta aqui lhe mostrar como usa o php e você querer de uma maneira que desconheço em qualquer linguagem que já programei. Espero que não entenda isto como uma critica construtiva pro seu aprendizado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
$meuArray = Array();
$file = fopen('numeros.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
  $meuArray[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
print_r($meuArray);
```

E para usar os valores de `$meuArrray`, basta usar um [**for**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php) ou um [**foreach**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) ou simplesmente setar um indice na variavel:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($meuArray); $i++){
echo $meuArray[$i];
}
```

ou

```
foreach($meuArray as $linha => $valor){
echo 'linha '.$linha.' = '.$valor;
}
```

---

Comment: Funcionou, mas eu gostaria de fazer algo nesse formato, ( $arrayItem = array($meuArray); )

Comment: Nao entendi, tente explicar um pouco mais. Do jeito que sugeri, já está salvando um indice por linha.

Comment: O resultado esta aparecendo assim: (  [108] => Array ( [0] => 8501060631 )  ) Como eu faço para apenas pegar o valor do array, ne caso é o numero 8501060631

Comment: O que é `$arrayItem`? Tente adicionar pelo menos um pedaço do seu csv e mostrar como voce quer separar os dados.

Comment: Eu estou utilizando esse codigo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96197/erro-webservice/96227?noredirect=1#comment196548_96227

Comment: Voce quer guardar um novo Array em `$arrayItem` somente com os valores do `$meuArray`? Não faz sentido algum isso. Basta usar o `$meuArray` dentro de um laço de repetição. Vou editar o código.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31264/discussion-between-desenvolvedor-and-diego-felipe).

Comment: Eu posso fazer só mais uma pergunta ?

Comment: @Desenvolvedor eu editei o código, agora faz o que você sugeriu.

Comment: Vou explicar melhor oque eu preciso

Comment: @Desenvolvedor Você mudou completamente o contexto da pergunta e isso não é recomendado, pois as resposta ficam sem sentido. Volte a pergunta como estava, marque como solucionada e crie outra com a nova duvida